# Difference in using '\n' and "\n"

Tags: php

Can someone tell me the difference in using '\n' and "\n"?
Anytime I add '\n' to my php echos the source code doesn't include line breaks, but if I use "\n" it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes define what is called a [literal string](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), escape sequences will be interpreted literally, for example `'abc\ndef'` will literally be interpreted as `abc\ndef` as opposed to `abc<newline>def`.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know there was that big of a difference. I believe it is time to edit some of my codes to improve them. Thanks.